# How to disable elements in expandablelistview?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using `ExpandableListView` with "groups" and "childs" elements. Is it possible to disable expanding some of group elements ? Do I need to change some code in Adapter or should I `override` `onclick` method?

Comment: you could simply call `.setClickbale()` on view

Comment: @ndeokar Thank you for your answer. But I don`t want to disable all group-elements, but I want to disable some of them

Comment: logically if you are disabling clicks of group elements that means you don't want to show child elements ? correct me if i'm wrong. you can override onclick and then restrict as you mentioned.

Comment: @ndeokar Yep, I don`t want to show child elements of last group. The main idea of my question is how should I restrict as I mentioned: override onclick method or write some code in adapter. Could you show some example code for doing this please?

Comment: try to use `setOnGroupClickListener` on your listview and check which position you clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setOnGroupClickListener` on your listview and return `true` on the position you want to disable to be expended

this will disable the first element to be expended

```
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (i==0){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Call .setClickable(false) on those group headers that shall not trigger on click.
Your adapter gets a call to `getGroupView`. This method returns the view that is displayed as the group header.
If you don't want this view clickable, call `.setClickable(false)`

```
    @Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        convertView = li.inflate(<<your header item>>, null);
    }

     if (isLastGroup)
        convertView.setClickable(false);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: This doesn`t work too, I compare groupPosition with my number 5 (I have 6 groups) and if result `true` i set clickable(false)..